# setDividerDrawable with 9patch not working in 4.0

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I'm using a 9patch image as divider between my tabs. It works fine, but it doesn't in Android 4.0. How do I get it working? I've tried anything. I don't know it's working with a normal png but I don't think so. My code:

```
tabHost = getTabHost();
tabHost.getTabWidget().setDividerDrawable(R.drawable.tab_divider);
```

The minimal SDK version is 4 and it's working on all versions except Android 4.0.
Does anyone know how to fix?

Comment: Same problem here. Did you solve?

Comment: Not solved yet, but I don't think anyone knows the answer.

Comment: Same problem... i am guessing setDividerDrawable is bugged in ice cream sandwich

Answer (score 0):

OK I just fixed this issue.  I have had to call setShowDividers() which needs API level 11 so the code is inside a version check as I work down to API level 7.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
    mTabHost.getTabWidget().setShowDividers(TabWidget.SHOW_DIVIDER_MIDDLE);
}
mTabHost.getTabWidget().setDividerDrawable(R.drawable.tab_divider);
```